# aguien quede decirme por que el texto teniendo espacio abajo prefiere salirse de la caja?

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aguien quede decirme por que el texto teniendo espacio abajo prefiere salirse de la caja?

Comment: nos podrías mandar tu css? además, mira esta [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: Bienvenido. Se nos dificulta ayudarte si no cargas el código. Así que al menos cargalo cómo texto por favor. De ser posible con su debido formato.

Comment: no se preocupen, la solucion era que 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' es una sola palabra entera y html no podia simplemente dividirla por eso el overflow

Comment: La propiedad de CSS word-wrap permite que las palabras largas se puedan dividir y pasar a la siguiente línea.

Comment: *no se preocupen, la solucion era que 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' es una sola palabra entera y html no podia simplemente dividirla por eso el overflow* -> Mentira, si se puede dividir. El problema es que no has hecho que se divida, que es diferente :)

Answer (score 0):

Añadiendo **word-wrap: break-word** al contenedor cuando la palabra no entre en el ancho del contenedor se cortará y pasará a la siguiente fila. De esta manera puedes logar lo que deseas

```css
.box {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
</div>
```